# Set default version of Php in CentOS 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos, centos7, vps

I have two versions of PHP in `opt/remi` folder `php56` and `php72`
but when I `php -v` on cmd it shows:

```
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

How to set default version to PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> I have two versions of PHP in opt/remi folder php56 and php72
>
> how to set default version to PHP 7.2

SCL are designed for parallel installation so don't alter default version in base system

Once the collection is enabled, the version will be used

```
$ scl enable php72 bash
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 17 2018 05:35:43) ( NTS )
```

If you want 7.2 to be the default version (base system) you should install it, according to [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) for "**Default / single version**" (and keep 5.6 as secondary version)

Comment: does scl enable survive reboot ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to type `scl enable rh-php72 bash` for that to work, though.

Comment: I'm using Centos 7 and I did as @lmtiaz said and it worked.

Comment: How can you revert this action, to disable this scl command?

Comment: exit (the shell) ;)

Comment: not persistent, goes back to old version if you close shell.

Answer (score 6):

**Change `php cli` version in Centos 7**

First, find your `php7`, run `phpinfo()` and get `path` or you can do with other ways. for me, it is:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/
```

then:

```
cd ~
. ~/.bash_profile
```

And:

```
alias php='/usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/bin/php'
```

**Now:**

`php -v`

> PHP 7.3.13 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2019 16:02:35) ( NTS )

Comment: Is this persistent after reboots?  I rebooted and this reverted back to the old php.  But I didn't do the 'cd ~
. ~/.bash_profile' part because I didn't know what that did.

Comment: not persistent, goes back to old version if you close shell.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file "/etc/profile.d/php.sh". Use pathmunge to add the path to your php bin you want as default on line one and save the file.

Example:

```
pathmunge /opt/remi/php73/root/bin
```

Reload your profile afterwards by logging in again.

Now if you do a which php and php -v you should see the following output in my case

```
[root@host etc]# which php
/opt/remi/php73/root/bin/php
[root@host etc]# php -v
PHP 7.3.4 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2019 13:48:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.4, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
   with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com  (unconfigured) v10.3.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by ionCube Ltd.
```

This is the preferred way to accomplish this task using tools that are already supplied on a minimal install. This also allows scripts and commands to hit the correct php binaries when accomplishing other tasks. Commands like, pear, pecl, phar, php-config. You want your experience to be global when setting the default, otherwise you might wind up still getting version 5.6's tools when trying to install an extension or complete another task.

Comment: While PATH is enough for PHP, it is not for other SCLs, ". scl_source enable xxx" is better (or "module load xxx" when available). These commands also redirect LD_LIBRARY_PATH, man pages, ...)

Comment: And again, if you want a single version, don't use SCL designed for multiple versions, see the wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 1):

```
module enable php74
```

for your understanding:

```
cat /opt/remi/php74/enable
export PATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin:/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/sbin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export MANPATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}
```

Comment: "scl" command uses the /opt/remi/php74/enable file, while the "module" command use the /usr/share/Modules/modulefiles/php74 file, but goal is the same.

Comment: and what is the difference between module php74 and Software Collection php74?

Comment: There is no difference, "scl" command or "module" command are only different way to enable the software collection. Both are available for package from my repository